# How to deal with splitted documents without reaching the Elasticsearch limits

Tags: elasticsearch, search, elasticsearch-aggregation

We have parent docs indexed in one index and child documents indexed in another. The reason for doing so is

1. performance, since we may have thousand of children docs.
2. to be able to paginate the children separately.

Previous setup was with [nested fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested) but we got performance issues and were not be able to properly paginate the children.

The search requirement is to be able to match against parent + children, i.e. bring the parent which has matching on itself or in children and the matching children as well [optional].

So we are using aggregations for children to get the parent id-s then making another query for parents using `OR` condition to be able to paginate the parents themself.
i.e. parent has matching OR has id from children matches

The current issue is that the aggregations response could be more than 10k (even multiple times) and we don't want to resolve it changing the config `search.max_buckets` cause it's more or less temporary solution and will perform slow.

Any idea how to deal with this setup/requirement to be able to paginate the parents, paginate children, sort parents, search thru parent + children, search thru the children only?

Comment: I need a full-text search in children, then the same search in parents including the id-s from first result.

Comment: example: post-comments
search term: "test" 
result should be posts which has "test" keyword in their fields or posts which has  "test" keyword in related comments fields.
In my case post and comments are in separate indices